# Example input for AWS CDK loadNestedStacks

Tags: java, aws-cdk

I'm wondering how to create an example parameter for `loadNestedStacks`.

```
private CfnInclude template;
template = CfnInclude.Builder.create(this, "Template")
                  .loadNestedStacks(**what goes here**)
                  .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Typescript equivalent answer.

Include the nested template and if you have tree's. the names of the nested stacks below it.

```
import * as cf from "@aws-cdk/cloudformation-include";
...
const cfnTemplate = new cf.CfnInclude(this, 'Template', {
        templateFile: 'my-template.yaml',
        loadNestedStacks: {
            'stack-name': {
                templateFile: 'my-second-template.yaml',
            }
        },
      });
// Note: cdk.CfnInclude is deprecated so you may need to pull in cloudformation includes.
```